# Copy data from one table to an other at a specific index position

Tags: excel, join, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I try to do something that would be a JOIN in SQL...but I have to do it in LibeOffice Calc:

There are two table-sheets, one containing an index value and an text, the other one contains an index and some other values. So it looks like this:

Table A: index | text

Table B: index | data1 | data2

They have to be merged at index value while Table B does not contain as much indices as table A. As a result something like this should appear at all positions where A.index is equal to B.index:

index | data1 | data2 | text

Any Idea how this can be done in LibreOffice Calc (not Base or any other database)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need an application of the function VLOOKUP just like below.

VLOOKUP example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y60qp3mlp023vzv/vlookup_example.png

Comment: OK, and how should it look like in my specific case?

Comment: The picture serves as a simple example of this function. in your case you should apply the function for the appropriate columns and rows (and sheets) of your data. If possible please upload a sample of your data in order to help me to be more specific!